# Is there a way to debug the app on receiving push notification using GCM?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

Initially my app is closed and when I receive a new message from GCM push service, I am starting a new activity from [onMessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService.html#onMessage%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) in my class which extends `GCMIntentService`. I want to use the debugger to check some errors. My question is that is there a way to Debug the app when started from the Push Notification?

To clear a bit more,  I have a `BroadcastReceiver` and a service attached to it. Even is the app is closed, it receives the broadcast and starts an activity based on the message received. **It is possible that the app receives the broadcast when it is not open. Now, when the app is open and I get a Push Message then I can debug it. But the problem is when when app is closed and it receives the broadcast, then how to debug it?**

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't start your app in debug mode with a set breakpoint and background it? You can't just connect a debugger on demand like this afaik

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Neiti01. I didn't get what do you mean by `background it..`. I am able start my app in debug mode from eclipse and set the breakpoints. The issue is if I exit the app from the device, then the debugging stops( which is expected). Now I have a BroadCastReceiver and a service attached to it. Even is the app is closed, it will receive the broadcast and start an activity.

Comment: It is possible that the app receives the broadcast when it is not open. Now, when the app is open and I get a Push Message then I can debug it. But the problem is when when app is closed and it receives the broadcast, then how to debug it? I hope the question is more clear now. Thanks for reading the long  comment patiently.

Comment: By "background it" I mean just press the home button. That shouldn't stop the process it should still be running and the debugger should still be attached and the breakpoint in your BroadCastReceiver will fire.

Comment: ohh. Yes I agree. For that case my Push is working fine if the app is in background. I am also able to debug that case. But when app is closed then it is not behaving as it used to. That's why I asked the question :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Did yout find a way to debug when app is called from a notification after receiving a GCM?

Comment: Contrary to @Neiti01, you can attach the debugger at any time.

Answer (score 25):

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    /*
      the following line will halt the app here
      to give you time to attach the debugger
    */
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

    /*
      then you can put a breakpoint on any line
      after that, like here:
    */
    Log.d("onMessageReceived", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    ...
}
```

You can put the line `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` anywhere in your code where you want to stop execution and attach the debugger. Just remember to remove it when you're done debugging.

Comment: Still working perfectly in July 2020! I would recommend always wrapping that in "if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)" to be safe.